# Swift - CompositionalLayout - calculate height

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I'm trying to create a grid of movie posters using `CompositionalLayout`.
But I'm struggling with cell height.
The problem is that when I set that I need to render 3 posters per row. It calculates width automatically so basically the width will be different on different devices.

Is there a way to maintain aspect ration or access the cell width to calculate height in `.absolute()`?

I also tried to use `.estimated(100)`, but it behaves the same as `.absolute(100)`

Here is my code how I'm doing it now, the cell height is hardcoded.

```
func moviesSection() -> NSCollectionLayoutSection {
    
    //define item
    let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
    
    //configurate item
    item.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 16, trailing: 16)
    
    //define group
    let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .absolute(160))
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: 3)
    
    
    //define section
    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    
    return section
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the height of the group to `fractionalWidth`. The code snippet below will make it so that the height of the cell is always 30% of the screen height. You could also write your own height determining logic and wrap it in .absolute(customHeight).

```
let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.3))
```

Comment: omg, I can't believe I've never thought about using `.fractionalWidth` in `heightDimension`. Thanks!